# My app not showing in mobile

Tags: android

I am running my App on my mobile through data cable . the app runs fine but does not show in the Apps on the mobile. It shows up in the application manager but no icon and no link to the app in the apps section . what could be the fault here.
kindly update

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.intel.myapplication.alumni2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="My App"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".MyApplication">

        <activity android:name=".Welcome">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="meriapp"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Registration">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="meriapp"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Slider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="meriapp"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Alumni">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="meriapp1"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Student">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="merapp1"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Authentication">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="merapp1"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Register_submit">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="meriapp1"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <!-- <activity android:name=".College_update">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="meriapp1"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>-->


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It seems that your app's manifiest incomplete. Can you post here your manifiest?

Comment: nearest cause `because that is a library-project`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare at least one of your activities in the manifest as the main launcher one for it to appear in the apps menu. To do so, add the following to the `activity` element:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Notice the all caps `LAUNCHER`. The manifest you posted has it as `Launcher`.

Comment: That is there. As i wrote the application runs fine when i run from android studio. but if i need to run as such from mobile there is no icon no link to launch.

Comment: You can manually select the activity to launch in Android Studio. The manifest you posted now has capitalization error in this intent filter.

Answer (score 0):

When you're running you're app in debug mode or in release (via APK for example) **it IS shown in you're app list**. I'm sure you are looking on the wrong application name, or you missed it.

*It just happens.*

Answer (score 0):

Check your **manifest.xml** file, weather you have write the below lines or not?

```
       <activity
            android:name="com.example.restaurent.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `android:label="My App"` tag in your launcher activity, this may help you.